# EF 6.1.3 Multiplicity conflicts

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have been getting error when I try to run add-migration script. 
The error is:

```
Domain.DataAccessLayer.AllRoutines_Product: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'AllRoutines_Product_Target' in relationship 'AllRoutines_Product'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.
```

And I cannot figure what I am doing wrong. I have AllRoutines and Product entities. AllRoutines can have 0 or 1 Products. Here is my AllRoutines class (some code has been omitted for clarity):

```
public class AllRoutines
{
    [Key]

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Tags { get; set; }


    public int? RoutineLevelId { get; set; }

    public RoutineLevel RoutineLevel { get; set; }


    public Guid? ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

}
```

Here is FluetnApi mapping (again some code is omitted):

```
public void MapRoutine(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<RoutineLevel>().HasKey(r => r.RoutineLevelId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<AllRoutines>()
            .HasKey(r => r.Id)
            .Property(r => r.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);


        modelBuilder.Entity<AllRoutines>()
            .HasOptional(r => r.RoutineLevel)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.RoutineLevelId);



        modelBuilder.Entity<AllRoutines>().HasOptional(c => c.Product)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ProductId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

Also I am not sure if this is important or not, but there is also class CustomRoutine which inherits AllRoutines and looks like this:

```
 public class CustomRoutine : AllRoutines
 {

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }


    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public User UserWhoCreatedRoutine { get; set; }

}
```

The inheritance approach was Table per Hierarchy.

I've tried to add to mapping configuration this:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<CustomRoutine>().HasOptional(c => c.Product)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ProductId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

But the error was same. I am not sure why this is happening, because, as you can see in the code same mapping was already done (without any problems) for RoutineLevel, also I have same mapping for Product and the other class, again with no problems.

**EDIT**
Here is also Product class:

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsFree { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SubscriptionProduct> SubscriptionProducts { get; set; }

}
```

And FluentAPI mapping:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasKey(p => p.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .Property(p => p.Code)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(10);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .Property(p => p.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany(p => p.SubscriptionProducts)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ProductId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Comment: Can you post the (relevant part of the) `Product` class / configuration

Comment: @IvanStoev I've updated the question :)

Comment: Can't reproduce with the provided model / configuration. The only way I can get the aforementioned error is if I make the `ProductId` property required by changing the type to `Guid`, applying `[Required]` attribute on it or using `modelBuilder.Entity<AllRoutines>().Property(r => r.ProductId).IsRequired();`

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for your help, but unfortunately I do not have required tag anywhere for ProductId prop :/

Comment: Hehe, I would say *fortunately* :) But still for some reason EF considers it required (custom convention, common code using `modelBuilder.Properties()` etc.). What happens if you add the following at the beginning of the mapping `modelBuilder.Entity<AllRoutines>().Property(r => r.ProductId).IsOptional();`?

Comment: @IvanStoev This helped !!! Thanks a lot :) You could write it as an aswer so I can mark it as accepted.